# Returning from :make to source code has sometimes a step too much

Tags: makeprg

To work with `pascal` files, my `.vimrc` contains this code:

```
"" Work with pascal files
augroup make_pascal
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType pascal :compiler fpc
  autocmd FileType pascal :set makeprg=clear;\ fpc\ %
augroup END
```

To demonstrate the issue I am experiencing see this easy hello-world-like demonstration code written in `pascal` which intentionally contains an error:

```
program EasyExample (output);

begin
  writeln ('Correct line.');
  thisWillCauseAnError;
end.
```

When I run `:make` on this file with my Vim cursor in any line that does not contain the error, everything works fine: the external `fpc` compiler gets called and aborts compilation due to an error. After pressing `ENTER` I get back to my source code and the cursor is in the line that contains the error, and the error message is displayed at the bottom.

But when I run `:make` on this file with my Vim cursor in the line that does contain the error, an additional step is added (and I would like to remove it): After the compilation abortion pressing `ENTER` does not get me back to my source code, but instead a new "window" (is that the quickfix list?) is shown with the following text at the bottom:

> (5 of 8): Error: Identifier not found "thisWillCauseAnError"
>
> Press ENTER or type command to continue

After pressing `ENTER` again I see my source code again, the cursor in the line that contains the error, and the error message is displayed at the bottom.

**Question**

How do I get rid of that additional "window" that appears, so that the behaviour when running `:make` is always the same (i.e. press `ENTER` once to see my source code with highlighted error)?

Comment: @saginaw: `:silent! make | redraw! | cw` is a great solution and is what I will use. Please post it as an answer (so that you get reputation and the vi/Vim site stats on Area51 get better) and I will happily accept it. It would be great if you could also mention a way how I could delete the `.o` file automatically after compilation, as the `autocmd` in my answer that deletes the object file does not work with the `:silent! make | redraw! | cw` command: the quickfix list is empty and does not contain errors.

Comment: Sorry I removed my comments because I thought they didn't solve your issue, but I'm glad if they helped you a little! I'm not comfortable writing an answer because I can't reproduce what you're experiencing on my machine, and I don't know how compilation or Pascal works. To remove automatically the `.o` file, maybe you could look at `:h autocmd-events` and see if there's an event which corresponds to a compilation. Maybe `QuickFixCmdPre` or `QuickFixCmdPost`? That would give something like `autocmd QuickFixCmdPost * !rm\ -f\ %:r.o` I didn't try it so it may not work as expected.

Comment: Sorry again, I read your comment too quickly. You say the quickfix list is empty so the events I mentioned won't work. Maybe `ShellCmdPost` then? You could also install a fire-once autocmd (the autocmd is installed and removed as soon as the command is executed) inside a function and call the latter from a mapping `,c` or a custom command `:CP`: http://vpaste.net/0t1i4

Comment: The previous code won't work because I mixed a shell and Vim command on the same line. Maybe this will work, but I'm not really sure: http://vpaste.net/DhNQG

Comment: @saginaw: I have a working solution now, thanks again for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

[saginaw](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/4939/saginaw) pointed out in a now deleted comment that running `:silent! make | redraw! | cw` instead of `:make` solves my problem. If I run it the program compiles, and if there is an error the QuickFix list is opened on the bottom and the line with the error highlighted.

I expanded his solution further to deal with something else:

Whenever the free pascal compiler `fpc` is run on a file `example.pas`, it produces an executable `example` as well as an object file `example.o`, which [can be deleted](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userse10.html) as I don't need it.

The final solution in my `.vimrc` is:

```
"" Work with pascal files
augroup make_pascal
  autocmd!
  autocmd FileType pascal :compiler fpc
  autocmd FileType pascal :set makeprg=clear;fpc\ %
  autocmd FileType pascal nnoremap <buffer> <leader>c
      \ :w <bar> silent! make <bar> redraw! <bar> cw <bar>
      \ exe "silent! !rm -f %:r.o" <bar> redraw! <CR>
augroup END
```